# Var is not accessible outside background block on feature test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm having the following feature test

```
RSpec.feature 'Show post', :type => :feature do

  background do
    post = create(:post)
    user = create(:user)
    sign_in_with user # do login
  end

  scenario 'can view a single post' do
    visit root_path
    click_link(href: post_path(post))
    expect(page.current_path).to eq(post_path(1))
  end
end
```

If I run this test I get the following error

```
Show post can show idividual post
     Failure/Error: click_link(href: post_path(post))

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `post' for #<RSpec::
```

Which I think is caused because the `post` variable inside `post_path` is not accessible from the `background`, am I right ??

If I move the code from the `background` to the test scenario, ie

```
scenario 'can show idividual post' do
    post = create(:post)
    user = create(:user)

    sign_in_with user

    visit root_path

    click_link(href: post_path(post))
    expect(page.current_path).to eq(post_path(1))
  end
```

the test passes.

The problem I guess in this cases is if I want to add another scenario I have to repeat these steps again and again. How can I solve this and keep my code DRY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating local variables which are not accessible outside the block they are created in.  Instead use instance variables which are created and available on the test instance

```
@post = create(:post)
...
click_link(href: post_path(@post))
```

On a side note, don't use the `eq` matcher with `current_path` if you want stable tests as you start testing JS capable pages.  Instead use the have_current_path matcher

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(post_path(@post)) # You can't assume id==1 either
```

Comment: Oh god! so silly me! I didn't think the most obvious thing! anyway, thank you very much! :-)

Comment: @Lykos you're welcome, make sure you read my update about `have_current_path` too, if you get used to using it from the beginning you'll thank me later.

Comment: I used it as you said, but this throws me an error`Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_current_path(post_path(@path))
     
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` I guess complaining about the id

Comment: @Lykos - sorry typo -- should have been `@post` not `@path`, you can't assume it will always be id 1 as you run more tests, and the method used for resetting the DB changes (some will clear the DB but not reset the index counters)

Comment: yeap! working now! Thank you again and thanks for the tip too!

Comment: Just one additional question: Does it make sence to use `let` in this case? e.g `let(:post) { create(:post) }  let(:user) { create(:user) }   background do ... end `

Comment: @Lykos That's personal preference - but realize that `let` evaluates lazily so the object doesn't exist until your reference it once in your test.  That means your test would fail because when you visit the root path the post will not yet have been referenced, hence not created, and no link will be on the page.  You can fix that by using `let!` for objects that must be created every time.